# Sequelize - How to pull records with 1 associated record and order by associated record attribute

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Convos table, which has many Messages.

What I want: pull all convos and last message. Order the convos by `last_message.created_at`

```
models.Convos.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Messages,
            as: "last_message",
            order: [ [ 'created_at', 'DESC' ]],
            limit: 1,
         }
    ],
    where:{
        [Op.or]: [
            {
                sender_id: req.decoded.id
            },
            {
                recipient_id: req.decoded.id
            }
        ],
    },
)}
```

The closest I've gotten to ordering is with :

```
order: [
  [{model: models.Messages, as: 'last_message'}, 'created_at', 'DESC'],
],
```

But this gives the error:

```
`Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "last_message"`
```

From here, I am guessing this error may allude that there are convos without any messages, making `last_message.created_at` undefined (I could be completely misunderstanding this error though).

So, from there, I have been trying to add a clause to the `where` statement that only pulls convos that have at least 1 message. Here are a bunch of things I've tried, and they all throw an error:

adding to where:

```
Sequelize.literal("`last_message`.`id` IS NOT NULL")


'$models.Messages.id$': { [Op.ne]: null },

Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("last_message")): { [Op.gt]: 0 }
'$last_message.id$': { [Op.ne]: null }

'$last_message.id$': {
  [Op.ne]: null
}
```

I've also tried `having` instead of a `where` statement:

```
having: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('$last_message.id$')), '>=', 0)
```

How can I properly sort the convos by it's associated record, `last_message.created_at`?

UPDATE - RELEVANT PARTS OF CONVOS MODEL

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  let Convos = sequelize.define(
    "Convos",
    {
      sender_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "Users",
          key: "id"
        }
      },
      recipient_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "Users",
          key: "id"
        }
      },
      created_at: DataTypes.DATE,
      updated_at: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      freezeTableName: true,
      schema: "public",
      tableName: "convos"
    }
  );

  Convos.associate = models => {
    Convos.hasMany(models.Messages, {
      as: "last_message",
      foreignKey: "convo_id",
      sourceKey: "id"
    });
  };

  return Convos;
};
```

**UPDATE**
I've figured out the issue is using Sequelize.literal when the associated model has `limit`. For example, this works:

```
models.Convos.findAll({
  include: [
  {
        model: models.Messages,
        as: "last_message",
        order: [ [ 'created_at', 'DESC' ]],
        //limit: 1,
        required: true,
        duplicating: false, 
    },
],
where: {
  [Op.or]: [
      {
          sender_id: req.decoded.id
      },
      {
          recipient_id: req.decoded.id
      }
  ],
},
order: [[Sequelize.literal(`last_message.created_at`), 'DESC']],
offset: offset,
limit: 10,
}).then(convos => { ....
```

But when I uncomment the `limit: 1` in the include part, I get the error: 
`Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "last_message"`

Here is the query logs without `limit 1`:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "Convos"."id", "Convos"."sender_id", "Convos"."recipient_id", "Convos"."created_at", "Convos"."updated_at", "last_message"."id" AS "last_message.id", "last_message"."body" AS "last_message.body", "last_message"."read" AS "last_message.read", "last_message"."group_meeting_id" AS "last_message.group_meeting_id", "last_message"."user_id" AS "last_message.user_id", "last_message"."created_at" AS "last_message.created_at", "last_message"."updated_at" AS "last_message.updated_at", "last_message"."convo_id" AS "last_message.convo_id", "last_message->user"."id" AS "last_message.user.id", "last_message->user"."first_name" AS "last_message.user.first_name", "last_message->user"."avatar_file_name" AS "last_message.user.avatar_file_name", "senderUser"."id" AS "senderUser.id", "senderUser"."first_name" AS "senderUser.first_name", "senderUser"."avatar_file_name" AS "senderUser.avatar_file_name", "recipientUser"."id" AS "recipientUser.id", "recipientUser"."first_name" AS "recipientUser.first_name", "recipientUser"."avatar_file_name" AS "recipientUser.avatar_file_name" FROM "public"."convos" AS "Convos" INNER JOIN "public"."msgs" AS "last_message" ON "Convos"."id" = "last_message"."convo_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."users" AS "last_message->user" ON "last_message"."user_id" = "last_message->user"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."users" AS "senderUser" ON "Convos"."sender_id" = "senderUser"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."users" AS "recipientUser" ON "Convos"."recipient_id" = "recipientUser"."id" WHERE ("Convos"."sender_id" = 32 OR "Convos"."recipient_id" = 32) ORDER BY last_message.created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 70;
```

Query with `limit: 1`:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "Convos"."id", "Convos"."sender_id", "Convos"."recipient_id", "Convos"."created_at", "Convos"."updated_at", "senderUser"."id" AS "senderUser.id", "senderUser"."first_name" AS "senderUser.first_name", "senderUser"."avatar_file_name" AS "senderUser.avatar_file_name", "recipientUser"."id" AS "recipientUser.id", "recipientUser"."first_name" AS "recipientUser.first_name", "recipientUser"."avatar_file_name" AS "recipientUser.avatar_file_name" FROM "public"."convos" AS "Convos" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."users" AS "senderUser" ON "Convos"."sender_id" = "senderUser"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."users" AS "recipientUser" ON "Convos"."recipient_id" = "recipientUser"."id" WHERE ("Convos"."sender_id" = 32 OR "Convos"."recipient_id" = 32) ORDER BY last_message.created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Here are some links that were useful in understanding `limit` is causing the issue, but I have still not found a solution that solves this problem.

[Link 1](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8432)

[Link 2](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9861)

[Link 3](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9507)

[Link 4](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4446)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to get the desired result without using sequelize.js ? Just by using SQL?

Comment: @madflow Like with pure SQL? I was attempting to write something with `Sequelize.literal("`last_message`.`id` IS NOT NULL")` The short answer is no - otherwise I would not have posted the question haha :) I understand the concept, but I'm struggling to get the correct syntax.

Comment: Then - please post your table structure and DB engine. Icing on the cake: Create a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ . Fromr there - it should be easy to convert it to the sequalize.js ecosystem.

Comment: Making a fiddle doesn't make sense - I don't know how to write this, which is the issue. The db relation is already stated - convo has many messages. You don't need the whole table structure for this question, it's more a question about sequelize syntax for `order` and `where` statements.

Comment: In the last bit where you stated `having` instead of `where`, shouldn't it be `>0` (not `>=`) - (Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('$last_message.id$')), '>', 0)

Comment: Also, if you're not willing to share how your models are defined/associated make sure that the associations are defined properly - this link may help https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/970

Comment: The error *missing FROM-clause entry for table "last_message"* is because the resulting query (query log) does not have any table called *last_message*. It seems that sequelize is ignoring the include.

Comment: @Dan you're so right! I just updated to showed a query log with `limit 1` (which doesn't include last_message), and without `limit 1`, which does have `last_message`. What could be causing this/how to fix? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I do not know sequelize. And - there are three documented versions and you have not stated which one you are using.

> What I want: pull all convos and last message. Order the convos by
>   last_message.created_at

I can offer a SQL (Postgres) solution.

I assume a convos table (something like):

```
CREATE TABLE convos (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  sender_id INT,
  recipient_id INT
);
```

and a messages table

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    convo_id INT REFERENCES convos (id),
    created_at timestamp  without time zone
);
```

And some test data:

```
INSERT INTO 
convos (id, sender_id, recipient_id) 
VALUES (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,4);

INSERT INTO 
messages (id, convo_id, created_at) 
VALUES 
(1,1, '1990-07-24'), 
(2,1, '2019-07-24'), 
(3,2, '1990-07-24'), 
(4,2, '2019-07-24'), 
(5,3, null);
```

When you want to query the `convos` table and fetch the latest message from `messages` table you will have to use the result from `messages` in a subquery (or a CTE, or lateral join, ...).

For example:

```
SELECT 
    convos.sender_id,
    convos.recipient_id,
    messages.last_message_date
FROM convos
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT convo_id, max(created_at) as last_message_date
    FROM messages 
    GROUP BY convo_id
) messages ON convos.id=messages.convo_id
ORDER BY  messages.last_message_date DESC
```

So for sequelize.js - you have to find out how it does subqueries with associated models and use the result.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the attempt. Did you read the part of my post with the update? It shows a working query, but if I try to limit to only 1 Message, then it throws an error. I'm using sequelize.js. As well - I put the convos model and the association in the question.

Comment: Yes - I have read the update. My view on this is: you can only limit the messages in a subquery. If sequelize has an api for that - or you can use `literal`, bingo. Maybe you can get help in their chat: http://sequelize-slack.herokuapp.com/.

Comment: And link this question.